# create dataframe from list of list python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have list of list(t):

```
[[{'CreationDate': b"D:20191125142104+05'00'",
   'Creator': b'PDF-XChange Editor 7.0.325.1',
   'ModDate': b"D:20191125142754+05'00'",
   'Producer': b'PDF-XChange Core API SDK (7.0.325.1)'}],
 [{'CreationDate': b"D:20200215153643+05'00'",
   'Creator': b'Adobe Acrobat 11.0.23',
   'ModDate': b"D:20200215191411+05'00'",
   'Producer': b'Adobe Acrobat Pro 11.0.23 Paper Capture Plug-in'}],
 [{'CreationDate': b"D:20200215153532+05'00'",
   'Creator': b'Adobe Acrobat 11.0.23',
   'ModDate': b"D:20200215191426+05'00'",
   'Producer': b'Adobe Acrobat Pro 11.0.23 Paper Capture Plug-in'}]]
```

I need create a DataFrame, where columns=['CreationDate', 'Creator', 'ModDate', 'Producer'].
I try to do next: pd.DataFrame(t, columns=['CreationDate', 'Creator', 'ModDate', 'Producer']) and I get error:

```
 4 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns
```

If I do pd.DataFrame(t[0], columns=['CreationDate', 'Creator', 'ModDate', 'Producer']), I get an one-row DataFrame.
How to do a good DataFrame?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select first lists from nested lists in list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x[0] for x in t])
```

Or flatten nested lists, then get all nested lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in t for y in x])
```

---

```
print (df)
                 CreationDate                          Creator  \
0  b"D:20191125142104+05'00'"  b'PDF-XChange Editor 7.0.325.1'   
1  b"D:20200215153643+05'00'"         b'Adobe Acrobat 11.0.23'   
2  b"D:20200215153532+05'00'"         b'Adobe Acrobat 11.0.23'   

                      ModDate  \
0  b"D:20191125142754+05'00'"   
1  b"D:20200215191411+05'00'"   
2  b"D:20200215191426+05'00'"   

                                            Producer  
0            b'PDF-XChange Core API SDK (7.0.325.1)'  
1  b'Adobe Acrobat Pro 11.0.23 Paper Capture Plug...  
2  b'Adobe Acrobat Pro 11.0.23 Paper Capture Plug...
```

Comment: Thanks! It's really helps me!

Answer (score 1):

Use concat and from_dict:

```
df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame().from_dict(x) for x in ls])
```